# Are We Living in a Simulated Universe?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

1. Isn't Quantization of Energy (or action) in Quantum Mechanics prove that our world is a Great Computer Simulation!?
2. Are We Living in a Simulated Universe?

just imagine the whole world is a great simulation, and the whole world started with a simulated big bang. and every things are results of spontaneous program self- organization and automorphisms. The big bang happened in a kind of supercomputer And now we're inside of it. the Big Bang occurred approximately 13.75 billion years to our eyes, But perhaps within less than a second for simulator.

1. If the universe is just a Matrix- like simulation, how could we ever know?

It seems to me the Quantum Mechanics Implies That The Universe is a Computer Simulation. E=nhυ where the h is planck constant and (n=1,2,3,...)

Laser fires single particles of light, called photons, through the slits. Even though only single photons of light are being fired through the slits and They create three pattern again. How single particles of light can create this wave pattern?

parallel worlds. They're here, millimetres away. And they're being created all the time. This vision of reality says that any time we go to work, there'll be another universe where we stay at home. It's a disturbing idea, developed in the 1950s, it's the best and only solution to the paradox at the heart of quantum reality. The big problem with quantum mechanics is that the little particles that we're all made of can be in multiple places at once According to this theory, when the photon of light faces two slits it doesn't split in two. It splits the world in two. Every photon in the double slit experiment creates a new parallel world.

Comment: Why should discreteness of features of the world prove that it is simulated in a machine? Does the climate in Antarctica prove that the world is in a refrigerator?

Comment: Why should discreteness of features of the world prove that it is simulated in a machine?
Because this is what I've chosen to believe

Comment: So, would it be fair to say that your question is just stating your personal opinion without making any argument for why it should be the case?

Comment: The root of all the particles is called quantum, And of course the root of world. Like all great simulated

Comment: What makes you a human and makes dog a dog is difference between yours DNA and dogs DNA, DNA is information And nothing more, and also what makes you sick is virus is information. just like computer.

Comment: Our picture of the universe is a slow motion, The world is rapidly expanding very fast, and we're all blast wave of big bang.

Comment: @Niel de Beaudrap can you
prove opposite, can you
prove world is not simulated.

Comment: No: but this is not the point. I'm not saying that you're wrong, or even offering an opinion on whether or not the world is simulated. I'm observing that you're asking the question rhetorically (which is discouraged in this site as well as the other StackExchange sites), and in particular making a key assertion which makes it difficult to engage with your question seriously as a philosophical problem. This is not a forum either to obtain or announce deep truths about the world, but to answer quesions about philosophical technique and existing philosophical writing on various subjects.

Answer (score 4):

Only just recently has a method been proposed to determine if the world is in fact a simulation. See ["proposed method to determine if the universe is a simulation"](http://phys.org/news/2012-10-real-physicists-method-universe-simulation.html) which refers to a recent paper from Cornell, ["Constraints on the Universe as a Numerical Simulation"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.1847)

A tiny glimpse of the method would be

> The numerical simulation scenario could reveal itself in the distributions of the highest energy cosmic rays exhibiting a degree of rotational symmetry breaking that reflects the structure of the underlying lattice.

Answer (score 0):

Quantum mechanics are discrete. They are not easily computable, ask any physicist.

If you are referring to the simulation argument, let this be known:

The simulation argument does **NOT** say that we live in a simulation.

The simulation argument is as follows:

1. Consider the following syllogism:

   - It is highly probably that future!humanity will have access to vast computation resources.
   - It is probably that some future!human will at some point simulate something resembling the civilisation of their ancestors.
   - *THUS* we are probably living in a simulation.
2. The above syllogism appears absurd.
3. The above syllogism is valid.

   - A valid syllogism is *true* when both it's premises are true.
   - A valid syllogism is *false* when either of it's premises are false.
   - The validity of a syllogism is distinct from it's truth.
4. Ponder the following: If the above syllogism is to be false in accordance with our intuitions of absurdity, which of the premises do we disagree with? Or do we disagree with the validity?

There is an reductionist answer, and it is that it doesn't matter, since a simulation is a "window" into a "universe," not a "universe" in itself. This observation is as follows:

1. Suppose we simulate a universe.
2. The simulation is a *physical* computer modelling a *mathematical* set of axioms.

   - The fact that 2 apples and 2 apples is 4 apples has no bearing on the the truth of arithmetic.
   - The apples is a *physical* system, modelling a *mathematical* set of axioms (Peano Arithmetic, for instance).
   - A computer is just a really complicated system of physical interactions behaving like Peano Arithmetic and other axiom sets.
3. *THUS* our simulation of them has no bearing on their reality.

There are problems with the view of universe as mathematics which number among others difficulty of defining consistent utilitarianism. This I will not go into detail with here.